# How can I set a default for star arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that accepts `*args`, but I would like to set a default tuple, in case none are provided. (This is not possible through `def f(*args=(1, 3, 5))`, which raises a `SyntaxError`.) What would be the best way to accomplish this? The intended functionality is shown below.

```
f()
# I received 1, 2, 3!

f(1)
# I received 1!

f(9, 3, 72)
# I received 9, 3, 72!
```

The following function `g` will provide the correct functionality, but I would prefer `*args`.

```
def g(args=(1, 2, 3)):
    return "I received {}!".format(', '.join(str(arg) for arg in args))

g()
# I received 1, 2, 3!

g((1,))
# I received 1!

g((9, 3, 72))
# I received 9, 3, 72!
```

Comment: Do you want  `args=(1,2,3)` for `f(1)` or `f(1,2)`?

Comment: @julivico When no arguments are given (`f()`), it should default to `args=(1, 2, 3)`. When any arguments are given, though, it should just use those. (`f(1)` should use `args=(1,)`, which it does.)

Comment: You can may be use that `if not args: args=(1,2,3)`. There isn't a pretty solution to set it like keyword parameter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If no arguments are received, `args` will be an empty tuple. You can't add a default value in the method signature itself, but you can check if `args` is empty and replace it with a fallback value inside the function.

```
def g(*args):
    if not args: 
        args = (1, 2, 3)
    return 'I received {}!'.format(', '.join(str(arg) for arg in args))
```

Comment: It's amusing that three almost identical answers were submitted at the same time. This might be an example of one of the principles in the [zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) *"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."*

Answer (score 11):

You could check whether `args` are truthy in your function:

```
def g(*args):
    if not args:
        args = (1, 2, 3)
    return "I received {}!".format(', '.join(str(arg) for arg in args))
```

If no `args` are passed to the function, it will result in a empty tuple,  which evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 4):

```
def g(*args):
    if not args:
        args = [1, 3, 5]
    return "I received {}!".format(', '.join(str(arg) for arg in args))
```